# Specifying libraries for cmake to link to from command line

Tags: cmake

I have a huge project managed with CMake and this project has hundreds of components each of them having own source files and each of them linking to a list of libraries, specified with `target_link_libraries(${project} some_libraries, some_other_libraries)`

Now, what I am aiming for is that:

Without actually modifying any of the `CMakeLists.txt` I want **ALL** the projects's target executable to link to some specific libraries.

Is  there a way of achieving this? Since this is a one time trial, I don't want to manually hunt down all the CMakeLists.txt files and modify them (yes, this is the other alternative). Just a note, I compile the entire project from command line, using `cmake` (no cmake gui).

Answer (score 17):

This is kind of a hack, but for a C++ project, you can use `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`.  For a C project, I think you would use `CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIRBARIES`.

Example for C++ that links to `libbar` and `libfoo`:

```
cmake ... -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES="-lbar -lfoo"
```

See the documentation here:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_LANG_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html

This won't be available for older versions of CMake; it was added some time after version 3.0.

Comment: There must be cleaner hack for this six years later, right?

Answer (score 3):

This is a dirty, dirty hack, so please only use it for testing.

You can actually overload the `add_executable` command by defining a function of the same name. Do this close to the top of the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
function (add_executable name)
    message("Added executable: " ${name})
    _add_executable(${name} ${ARGN})
    target_link_libraries(${name$} your_additional_lib)
endfunction()
```

Note that `_add_executable` is an internal CMake name that may break in future CMake versions. As of now (version 3.0) it seems to work with all versions though.

You can overload `add_library` the same way if required.

For more fine-grained control over what is linked, instead of calling `target_link_libraries` you can also mess with the [`LINK_LIBRARIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) and [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) target properties directly.

Comment: indeed adds the libraries (libz pthread) as expected ... however it adds them at the beginning of the library list, so I get: `-rdynamic -lz -lpthread ../../libfappcore.a -lQtXml -lQtSql -lQtNetwork -lQtCore ../../../externals/gmock/libgmock.a ../../../externals/gmock/gtest/libgtest.a` unfortunately the linker fails: `undefined reference to symbol 'deflate'` ... if I add manually to the end of the compile command (like: `-rdynamic  ../../libfappcore.a -lQtXml -lQtSql -lQtNetwork -lQtCore ../../../externals/gmock/libgmock.a ../../../externals/gmock/gtest/libgtest.a -lz -lpthread`) it works :(

Comment: @fritzone I see. In that case, do not call `target_link_libraries` directly. Instead, save all the names of your executables to a list. Then, _at the very end_ of your top-level CMakeLists, [`foreach`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/foreach.html) over the list and call `target_link_libraries` there.

Comment: This is indeed an excellent idea and I like it a lot, unfortunately does not work: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:87 (target_link_libraries):
  Attempt to add link library "pthread" to target "CoreMessageUnitTests"
  which is not built in this directory.`